# Identify tower being used in iOS

Tags: iphone, hardware

At my cottage field test mode tells me I am -116 dB. I need a booster with a yagi.

The problem is where to aim it. There are two towers about the same distance but very different directions.

Is there anything in field test that lets me identify the exact tower I’m using?

Answer (score 1):

I like to just do speed tests as you adjust the antenna when I don’t have a software defined radio and/or oscilloscope to measure the actual signals.

I’ve not seen any good tool that uses the compass or just shows that weak a signal since the noise is so large compared to the signal.

So, no - you’ll need to try them sequentially and also sight things visually or do even more measurements.

Hopefully someone has a better guide to field test, it’s so changeable based on hardware I try to do anything else but use that anymore. It was great when ATT and iPhone original came out, but after a while it’s needing a PHD to decipher.

Answer (score 1):

### <sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub> [Signal Reborn](https://repo.packix.com/package/com.charliewhile.signalreborn/)

If your device is jailbroken, you can use Charlie While's Signal Reborn on Packix. This will show the tower your device is connected to and other towers that your phone has previously seen, which can be filtered to only show towers for your carrier.

> Its main purpose is to map out all the cell towers that are in your local area. It does this through all on device measurements, meaning it's always up to date. The tower you are currently using, will have a green outline, and a green line going to it.
>
> [image]

Comment: Well it's not jailbroken, but still this is extremely useful info. I'll talk to the author and see if he can let me in on how it works.